# typeahead.js and rails search, remote option not displaying results

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, typeahead.js, bootstrap-typeahead

I'm trying to complete an autocomplete searchbar (for titles and description of photos) on a project. My partner on this project has implemented the following search action in the Photos controller

```
def search_results
  tag =  params[:q].values.first
  puts(tag)
  @photos= @q.result(distinct: true).to_a
  @photos += Photo.tagged_with(tag).flatten
  @photos.uniq!
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @photos }
    end 
end

//And in my application.js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#typeaheadBar').typeahead([
   {
     name: 'mysearch',
     displayKey: 'title',
     remote: '/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q%5Btitle_or_caption_cont%5D=%QUERY'
   }
 ]);

});
```

I can't see what's wrong, but my instructor says I'm close, I know typeahead is returning something, but I don't know how to reference it. Could someone point me in the right direction or point out what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

typeahead does not have `remote` option in the dataset definitions. See the available options [here](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets). You should use the Bloodhound suggestion engine to fetch your data from remote. You can find examples [here](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/). In your case:

```
var engine = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('title'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: '../data/films/queries/%QUERY.json'
});

engine.initialize();

// The first argument is an option object, the additional arguments are 
// the definitions of your datasets.
$('#typeaheadBar').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'mysearch',
  displayKey: 'title',
  source: engine.ttAdapter()
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I sorted it out by changing my controller to only spew out titles but implement your suggestion so I can search for both. Thank you for pointing out that typeahead does not have the remote option as well.